# Get file paths relative to a script's folder for use with Copy-Item

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the command below to copy a file from the script directory. Since this script directory will be different on each PC how can I tell the -Path to use the file where the script is being run?

Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\user\test.certs' because it does not exist.

```
Copy-Item -Path .\test.certs -Destination "$env:UserProfile + '\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security'"
```

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot test.certs)` should work for you.

Comment: I get this error when I try that Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.

Comment: @user1342164 `$PSScriptRoot` only works when your code is actually saved to a file. If you try it at the command line or within ISE without saving, it will be blank.

Comment: I saved and closed it and ran the ps1 file from a powershell window and still get the error

Comment: if your PowerShell version isn't V3+ use $scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition instead of $PSScriptRoot

Comment: As an aside: `"$env:UserProfile + '\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security'"` does not work as intended; it should be `($env:UserProfile + '\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security')`; alternatively: `"$env:UserProfile\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
$ScriptPath = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
Copy-Item -Path ($ScriptPath + "temp.txt") -Destination "$env:UserProfile + '\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security'"
```

I generally use this method because it allows you to append a filename to it without any issues.

Comment: `Get-Item -Path ".\"` returns the _current_ location, which may or may not be the _script_'s. (As an aside, `$PWD` is an easier way to reference the current location, and `-Verbose` serves no purpose here).